# Android build error: Cannot evaluate module RCTVideo : Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get set up using https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video for an android version of a react-native app. After making all the changes to the various gradle files I'm running into this issue below.

I'm a bit of a novice with Android development, and I think I'm just making a silly mistake which is why I'm asking the question here rather than raising an issue. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
$ react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot evaluate module RCTVideo : Configuration with name 'default' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.851 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Edit, settings.gradle looks like this:

```
    rootProject.name = 'app_name'

include ':RCTVideo', ':app'
project(':RCTVideo').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android')
```

Comment: Can you show your Settings.gradle?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, settings.gradle is included in an edit.

Comment: Did you use the npm install version or pull the library from github directly?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the Settings.gradle my guess would be that the project location isn't going into the folder that has the gradle for the android version of the library. I would recommend added /android at the end of the path if it isn't there already.

I will update this answer when the Settings.gradle is provided.

-- Edit after additional information provided --

The version available on NPM is from 3 months ago. It looks like they didn't start adding Android support till Oct 30th and have continued working on it. As such you likely don't actually have the Android code in your node_modules folder. You can either wait till they push an update to NPM or install directly from the git repo. If you go the route of installing directly from the git repo you might want to tag it with a specific commit so you don't keep getting the latest every time you do a npm install.